24.10, nvidia, and wayland problem ; nvidia gpu quadro p520, nvidia driver 560, kde plasma ; diff between built and installed module
I upgraded from a fresh installation of 24.04 to 24.10 in the hope that I could use the NVIDIA Quadro p520 GPU and Wayland on my Lenovo P14S 1st gen, intel core i7-10510U. I am running KDE Plasma 6.1.5, kernel 6.11.0-1004-lowlatency (64-bit).
The NVIDIA GPU does not run.
nvidia-smi from the command line hangs.
dkms status` from the command line yields: 

```none
nvidia/560.35.03, 6.11.0-1004-lowlatency, x86_64: installed   
(WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)  
(WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)  
(WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)  
(WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)  
(WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
nvidia/560.35.03, 6.8.0-45-lowlatency, x86_64: installed


nvidia-bug-report.sh from the command line hangs, however the voluminous nvidia-bug-report.log.gz includes the following:
<warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-14 (Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2) 14.2.0
  You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2) 14.2.0
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1 
 cmd_mod /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia.mod
  printf '%s
'   nvidia/nv.o nvidia/nv-pci.o nvidia/nv-dmabuf.o nvidia/nv-nano-timer.o nvidia/nv-acpi.o nvidia/nv-cray.o nvidia/nv-dma.o nvidia/nv-i2c.o nvidia/nv-mmap.o nvidia/nv-p2p.o nvidia/nv-pat.o nvidia/nv-procfs.o nvidia/nv-usermap.o nvidia/nv-vm.o nvidia/nv-vtophys.o nvidia/os-interface.o nvidia/os-mlock.o nvidia/os-pci.o nvidia/os-registry.o nvidia/os-usermap.o nvidia/nv-modeset-interface.o nvidia/nv-pci-table.o nvidia/nv-kthread-q.o nvidia/nv-memdbg.o nvidia/nv-ibmnpu.o nvidia/nv-report-err.o nvidia/nv-rsync.o nvidia/nv-msi.o nvidia/nv-caps.o nvidia/nv-caps-imex.o nvidia/nv-host1x.o nvidia/nv_uvm_interface.o nvidia/libspdm_aead.o nvidia/libspdm_ecc.o nvidia/libspdm_hkdf.o nvidia/libspdm_rand.o nvidia/libspdm_shash.o nvidia/libspdm_rsa.o nvidia/libspdm_aead_aes_gcm.o nvidia/libspdm_sha.o nvidia/libspdm_hmac_sha.o nvidia/libspdm_internal_crypt_lib.o nvidia/libspdm_hkdf_sha.o nvidia/libspdm_ec.o nvidia/libspdm_x509.o nvidia/libspdm_rsa_ext.o nvidia/nvlink_linux.o nvidia/nvlink_caps.o nvidia/linux_nvswitch.o nvidia/procfs_nvswitch.o nvidia/i2c_nvswitch.o nvidia/nv-kernel.o | awk '!x[$0]++ { print("/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/"$0) }' > /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia.mod
 SYMLINK /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
 ln -sf /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia/nv-kernel.o_binary /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
 cmd_mod /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia-uvm.mod
  printf '%s

nvtop from the command line shows the NVIDIA quadro p520 and the Intel integrated graphics cometlake-u gt2 (uhd graphics), but NVIDIA is not using any GPU cycles and is not using any memory when NVIDIA PRIME profile is set to "on demand".

When NVIDIA PRIME profile is set to "performance", some GPU memory is used but no CPU cycles are consumed.

nvidia-settings from the command line yields, in part :

(nvidia-settings:55158): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:38:46.626:
g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed


I am close to doing a fresh install of 24.10, but I am hoping for a quicker possible solution, especially as I'd not like to face the same problem after a fresh install.

My answer to this problem is to revert back to 24.04, after spending too much time  to reinstall 24.10 several times, try different nvidia drivers, tweak settings for the gpu, etc. etc.

By "back to 24.04", I should specify back to 24.04 and Xorg.
